# GAE/J-JDO select by entity type returns outdated result

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo, datanucleus

Investigating a problem for a while now. So asking the community.
My aim is to fetch all entities of specific kind and they all need to be up to date. (not taking into account any transaction isolation for now - can be dirty read)

I use GAE/J-JDO for that (use of tx.begin() is just a precaution):

```
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    Query q = pm.newQuery(TokenJdo.class);
    List<TokenJdo> tokenList = (List<TokenJdo>) q.execute();
    Collection<TokenJdo> res = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(tokenList);
    tx.commit();
    pm.close();
    for (TokenJdo t : tokenList) {
        log.info(t.getToken() + " - " + t.getCounter());
    }
```

Doing this gives me outdated entities (I request a list, go to AppEngine Console and modify one entity, request a list once again).
So I wrote a following debug code using DatastoreService directly.

```
    DatastoreService ds = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query gaeQuery = new com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query(TokenJdo.class.getSimpleName());
    PreparedQuery pq = ds.prepare(gaeQuery);
    List<Entity> list = pq.asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
    for (Entity i : list) {
        log.info(i.getKey() + " - " + i.getProperties());
    }
```

Executing both pieces of code in one request gives following output and shows that data via JDO is outdated compared to what DatastoreService returns:

```
I 2013-03-20 12:31:16.950 com.serverside.bl.TokenProviderJdo getAll: dummy - -999
I 2013-03-20 12:31:16.950 com.serverside.bl.TokenProviderJdo getAll: asd - 0
I 2013-03-20 12:31:16.951 com.serverside.bl.TokenProviderJdo getAll: dummy-aaa - -111
I 2013-03-20 12:31:16.957 com.serverside.bl.TokenProviderJdo logDSEntities: TokenJdo(7003) - {token=dummy, counter=-999}
I 2013-03-20 12:31:16.957 com.serverside.bl.TokenProviderJdo logDSEntities: TokenJdo(12001) - {token=asd, counter=0}
I 2013-03-20 12:31:16.957 com.serverside.bl.TokenProviderJdo logDSEntities: TokenJdo(13001) - {token=dummy-aaa, counter=-222}
```

Apparently (or as it looks to me) JDO uses some kind of internal cache (L1 or L2, though I didn't enable any explicitly). How do I make JDO do a 'clean' read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop `datanucleus` from caching anything you should disable both caching levels:

```
datanucleus.cache.level1.type=none
datanucleus.cache.level2.mode=none
```

Or you can disable caching per `Query` or per `PersistenceManager`, just set the mentioned keys using the `Query`'s or `PersistenceManager`'s methods.

On the other hand, you should detach you objects when needing to use them after looking them up. I'm not quite sure about the technical reason for this since the `PersistenceManager` should be closed before returning from the method using it, or so I learned, but after disabling all caching, you have to fully detach the looked up object before using it.

Comment: turning off the L1 cache should almost NEVER be done, unless you want to risk multiple copies of the same object. Turning off the L2 cache under some circumstances makes sense, though the property ought to be  datanucleus.cache.level2.type

Comment: Thanks Muhammad! That helped me find the last step in solving the problem. But actually I didn't find how to set the L2 property per `PM` or `Query` and I do not want to disable L2 globally in `PMF`. So in my case the proper solution is to set `setIgnoreCache(true)` on `PM` instance.

Comment: @NeilStockton, I understand but this is the only thing I could do for my app to always lookup the object from the database since I may update the record in the database using another tool an still the change isn't reflected in my application. I'll be grateful if you share how can this be done without disabling `L1` cache. Thank you

Comment: @yny, you just set the key in a properties map: `pm.getProperties().put(key, value)`. And the `setIgnoreCache(true)` is a great catch, thank you :)